# Wiring Every Room With Cat8 Ethernet

Tags: data-wiring, ethernet

I want to have 2 or 3 Ethernet jacks in every room in my house.  There are none anywhere currently.  Is my understanding correct in that I must use a switch?  The ISP's coax cable going into the modem, cat8 from the modem to the switch, and then a separate cat8 going to every individual jack in the house?  Alternatively, is there a way to daisy chain all the jacks together like you can with electrical wiring?  I have read about ethernet splitters but have also read that since they are not "smart" the data being transmitted might not go where it was intended to go, and that signal quality might degrade; any truth to that?

Also, can I have 2 modems connected to the same coax cable line?  For example, if I have my ISP's modem in the living room now and want to put another modem in the bedroom so that I can connect a small switch to it and connect all of my devices in my bedroom to it via ethernet, would this work?  Any signal degradation?

Comment: Cat 8 ???? Really? Cat 5e or 6 should be plenty. Do you actually need more than Gigabit speed?

Comment: How much work are you planning to do for this? Running ethernet wires in a finished house is non-trivial, unless your house has ugly office-like drop ceilings, or you are OK with seeing wires all over the place stapled to your walls.

Comment: I'm planning on digging up a lot of walls and repairing them afterwards. I've done this type of work before.  I plan on using smurf tubing for this job in order to future-proof the whole house.  I look at it as a selling point when I go to sell my place in a year or two.  Cat8 isn't that expensive so why not install the latest and fastest?

Comment: @Vlad: Cat8 isn't futureproofing, it's technology rapidly approaching obsolescence. Hard wired connections are increasingly simply a clumsy alternative to Wifi, and devices are increasingly set up to use Wifi first and we're seeing hard connections getting dropped altogether.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to for Cat8. None. Cat6 will do 10GBase-T up to 60m. Nothing more is needed, it's just a numbers game. Take it from me (I've used Cat6A at work, it's horrible). Installing Cat8 *Properly* (so that it actually will support whatever speeds it claims to), will be hard and expensive. Really - Cat 6 is ample.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is principally about computer networking, not home improvement.  Although the network is intended for a home, the questions asked are not pertinent to the installation.

Comment: I suggest you buy an introductory book or take an online course about computer networking, and attempt to build your network in a "laboratory" (i.e. your garage, or basement, or kitchen even) in order to learn some basics before you go to a lot of expense building something into your house that you do not sufficiently understand.

Comment: I think a question you might want to ask this community is "How should I approach building a network in my home so that I can do XXXXXX". where XXXX is what you want to do.   If you want to install smart TVs and use laptops and phones and all the sorts of things most people do in their homes, you do not need any cables, let alone Cat8, in most rooms.   Explain what you want to end up achieving, by building something in your home, and you should get some good advice here. But in fact, a simple google search will get you that for typical home network needs.

Comment: But ask @jay613's question in the proper forum. This isn't the proper SE site to ask networking questions. [networkengineering.se] _might_ be the right place, but you'd have to read their "On Topic" page in their help center to know for sure.

Comment: @FreeMan maybe this gets a bit meta but I think the question belongs here if it is, *What is a good strategy in my home (given size, construction, room use etc) to combine some wired and some wireless devices and provide power and ethernet for them for an effective and economical way to provide network to devices XXXX for purpose YYY in rooms ZZZ. *.  I think that's a home improvement question.  It may be too broad for SE but if it can be scoped down enough I think it's the right forum.

Comment: a bunch of ugly plates for an obsolete medium would be a turn-off for me, and i have Netwok+ certification...

Comment: I re-wired my house - primarily so that every TV has an optional hardwired Cat 6 connection.  I also included COAX, HDMI, etc. via an AV panel.  I think this is a good place to ask, but so is Network Engineering (or similar).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing You are up for tearing up the walls, prepare for some fun.

Yes, you will need a switch. Or router. Or can plug into whatever your internet service provider provided - this can be decided after all remodeling is done.

Running 'smurf tubbing' is a good call - I assume this is some kind of ribbed tubbing - you can also use a straight electrical pipes, they come in all sizes.

Ethernet jacks count: 2 per room is minimum, 4 or 6 for large rooms is recommended. When in doubt, go overboard. I have PC, laptop and tv in room that had only 2 jacks prepared and had to run extra cable. Adding more space is easy once you have walls open.

No, ethernet cables cannot be daisy-chained. That was done for telephone - ethernet needs one-to-one connections. If hiring help, do not get telephone guy, who will run one cable to all outlets in house and splice it along the length.

Cat8 is an overkill. You can do it, but you will need to take extra care and spend more on something unnecessary. Look at price of cat8 network devices and quake in fear. 99% sure none of your end devices have port faster than 1Gbit. Since you plan on tubbing in walls, you can simply replace the cable when technology gets cheaper. Cat 6E is plenty enough for home uses.

**How to build:**

Step1. Pick central location. All the ethernet cables have to meet at single location where you will put your switch. Dry basement works, or a cabinet/alcove you do not use. Use a location that has good access/free place to run the cables and has access to all floors. If it is reasonable, you can plan a switch-per-floor, if running 10 cables over large distance would be troublesome. Remember that you will need to power those extra distribution locations and buy extra switches.

> Example: In my house the central 'server room' is in dry basement, on the wall that has unused ventilation shafts. Cables from all rooms and floors run to that shaft in pipes/tubes, then connect at patch panel. I've also recently 'persuaded' my internet provider to move their cable to enter basement directly instead of zig-zagging through whole house (by doing most grunt work).

Step2: decide between patch panel or bare cable runs. The first one needs extra tool and materials, but saves you rework and dangling cables when you move devices. I recommend first option For patch panel, 24 jack one should do, unless your house is bigger, then install multiple. You can get a professional rack for servers, or screw two poles a correct width apart or even repurpose an ikea table. For patch panel option you will also need wall plates with punch-down connections.

Step3: Rip all walls open and put the tubing/pipes in. Make a run from central distribution location to every room. Put standard outlets where needed. You can either use modular electric outlet system and put them next to electric outlets, or give them some spacing. I have mine next to electric outlets in separate boxes (ethernet and mains should not mix!). For long cable runs, plan a spacious pull boxes. 10m is max you will be able to comfortably pull the cable, subtract 1m for every 90 degree turn on the way.

Step 4. Pull the cables. Leave extra couple feet on both sides. Do not bend too much, do not drag it over sharp kinks. Use cable crimp and LSA punch tool to punch the cable into panel, one per jack. Please use T-568A or T-568B standard. Punch the cables into wall plates. Test with lan tester. Label each jack with a number/code.

> Example: My house has the rooms numbered 1-15 and each jack is designed by letter. So my living room is 6A/6B on the panel. Bathrooms and kitchen do not have ethernet, although I wish the latter had.

Step5: Connect patchcords to router/switch and your devices on other side. You do not need to connect every one on the panel - only those you have devices on. In future, you may want a big sized 'rack' switch and just have all jacks active so you don't have to switch cables around if you move devices.

Step6 - bonus. Do you want cameras? IP cameras are cheap and work on same cables. You can power them with ethernet too. Into patch panel they go!

*Tools*:

- Nylon pull-string device for pulling the cable through piping.
- Crimper for RJ45 (+ LSA punch tool if you decide for wall plates)
- Lan cable continuity tester.

*Materials*

- A roll of CAT 6E cable. Make sure it is *copper* not a chinese fake with aluminium wire. If you really want cat8 and can stomach the cost, go for it.
- A patch panel for ethernet + wall plates with punch-down connections. Make sure they are cat8 rated if you plan on that. Plates can be replaced later if necessary.
- If you use patch panel + wall plates -> a bunch of patchcords in various sizes (1m, 2m, 5m) for connecting everything. Buy them once you know how much you need with some spares. I do not recommend crimping your own cables - takes too long and prone to errors.
- If going without panel and plates - a bag of rj45 jacks.

Comment: FYI, those "pipes/tubes" are usually called "conduit". It's the proper term to search for or ask for at the store, and it's less typing. ;)